# Conversion error when trying to match array to drop down list

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to "auto" select a value (client) based on what is inserted into a `sql` column on a `on click` event. The code I have is not working. I am trying to pull all the strings from the array and match it to my drop down list named layouts.

```
SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand($"SELECT Clients FROM users WHERE Email = @email;
SqlDataReader myreader;
con.Open();
myreader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
List<String> Clients = new List<String>();
while (myreader.Read())
{
    strValue=myreader["Clients"].ToString();
    strValue=myreader.GetString(0);
    string[] client1 = strValue.Split('|');
    foreach (string client in client1);

 if (client1.Equals(layouts));
    {
        ListItem selectedListItem = layouts.Items.FindByValue(client1);
        if (selectedListItem != null)
        {
            selectedListItem.Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know the name of the method you're trying to call? Can you show us the code where you call it?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. This code is not complete as it does not include the call site where the error occurrs.

Comment: This is the method I am trying to call.

Comment: @rjbyron1013 Fine, but we need to see where you're calling it from to determine why it's not working.

Comment: Show us where you call it. Find the method here you try to call it, edit your question, and paste that whole other method into your question as text. Also: Are you absolutely sure it's in the same class?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, I am absolutely sure as there is only one class.

Comment: A method declared `void` cannot return a value, and you're not calling it because there are no parentheses after the name.

Comment: Also, assuming you copied and pasted the code into the question (let's hope you did), the method is named `GetClientNames` (get client names) and yet you say you're calling `GetClientsNames` (get *clients* names).

Comment: @madreflection Is there another way to call that method? I am trying to pull a value from a `SQL` column to "auto" check a `checkbox.`

Comment: The *only* way is to use the right name and the right syntax. Right now, it's not about doing it a different way. You're just not doing it.

Comment: @rjbyron1013 When he says you're calling it wrong because there are no parentheses after the name, he's telling you to put parentheses after the name, just like every other method call in your code. Since you refused to show us the rest of the method like I asked you, it's difficult to guess what you want to do with the results of this call. Can you show us the rest of the method?

Comment: Before you can call it, you need to establish where you're getting the email (address) that it expects. Is that in a text box?

Comment: @madreflection Yes correct.

Comment: Since you haven't identified it *specifically* by control name, let me make an assumption: `List<string> emails = GetClientNames(textBox1.Text);`

Comment: EmailTextBox.Text

Comment: As a side note, the way that email addresses are being stored is a bad design. Your `users` table should have a child table with one row per address instead of a single column with pipe-delimited values. This is a fundamental aspect of database design called "normalization".

Comment: The emails are not pipe delimited. The clients are pipe delimited.

Comment: Well, you're missing the point. Those belong in a child table, whatever they are.

Comment: *Anything* pipe delimited in a database is a terrible, terrible idea. Stay off the pipe.

Comment: It defines user access. When a specified email has access to multiple clients, it pipe delimits. When your talking about 300+ clients how else do you it? A massive table and each client has their own column with a 1 or 0 value?

Comment: On the surface, it sounds like you're looking for a many-to-many relationship. However, the review note was not intended to escalate to a larger discussion so the last I'm going to say about it is this: Data normalization is a well-defined, well-discussed, time-tested practice. Read about it, learn it, and apply it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200422/discussion-on-question-by-rjbyron1013-issue-when-calling-a-method-c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to pass parameter to `GetClientsNames` method.

and you don't need to use return :)

you can write

```
GetClientsNames("you'r email");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two major problems:

1- `GetClientsNames` must have its arguments `string email`.

2- `AddPullButton_Click` can't return `GetClientsNames` as it is a `void` method, you can put the results in a `List<string>`.

```
protected void AddPullButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> results = GetClientsNames("some email");
}
```